# ML.NET export to ONNX

Tags: onnx, ml.net-model-builder

NET GUI tools to train model. The model works great with C# application, but I want to have it in ONNX format. I have found tools which are converting between model formats, but couldn't find anything for ML.NET generated format. Apparently it's some zip file, and nothing more I know about it. does anyone know a tool to do conversion to ONNX.
Thanks

Microsoft's ML.Net Model Builder generates code

```
    // Load Data
                IDataView trainingDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<ModelInput>(
                                                path: TRAIN_DATA_FILEPATH,
                                                hasHeader: true,
                                                separatorChar: ',',
                                                allowQuoting: true,
                                                allowSparse: false);
    
                // Build training pipeline
                IEstimator<ITransformer> trainingPipeline = BuildTrainingPipeline(mlContext);
    
                // Train Model
                ITransformer mlModel = TrainModel(mlContext, trainingDataView, trainingPipeline);
    
                // Evaluate quality of Model
                Evaluate(mlContext, trainingDataView, trainingPipeline);
    
                // Save model
                SaveModel       (mlContext, mlModel, MODEL_FILE, trainingDataView.Schema);
    
    
                var path = GetAbsolutePath(MODEL_FILE);
                path = new FileInfo(path).Directory.FullName;
                path = Path.Combine(path, "mymodel.onnx");
    
                using (var onnx = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    mlContext.Model.ConvertToOnnx(mlModel, trainingDataView, onnx);
                }
```

from

```
var path = GetAbsolutePath(MODEL_FILE);
                path = new FileInfo(path).Directory.FullName;
                path = Path.Combine(path, "mymodel.onnx");
    
                using (var onnx = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    mlContext.Model.ConvertToOnnx(mlModel, trainingDataView, onnx);
                }
```

I have modified.
I am getting onnx file, but I am not able to run it(inference). Likewise, I have tried to open it with WinML Dashboard, but it's also not able to run generated onnx. I wonder perhaps it's the version of the onnx it generates?
the model is simple regression with all inputs float numbers and output one float as well.

Comment: Have you got a solution to your problem? I have the same issue. I want to train a model using the model builder and then convert it to onnx, but have no success so far. The Onnx converter package does not work and throws an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Microsoft.ML.OnnxConverter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ML.OnnxConverter) NuGet Package.  Something like this:

```
var mlContext = new MLContext();

...

IDataView trainingData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(inputData);

var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", ... )
    .Append(...));

var model = pipeline.Fit(trainingData);

using (var onnx = File.Open("mymodel.onnx", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    mlContext.Model.ConvertToOnnx(model, trainingData, onnx);
}
```